# GroupLayout alignment

Tags: java, alignment, grouplayout

Why does ...

```
Group horizontalGroup = groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup()
            .addComponent(aTextArea)
            .addComponent(aButton,GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER));

Group verticalGroup = groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
    .addComponent(aTextArea)
    .addComponent(aButton);
```

... give this (as expected)

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|+-------------------------------------------------------+     |
||                       aTextArea                       |     |
||                                                       |     |
|+-------------------------------------------------------+     |
|                        [aButton]                             |
|                                                              |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

but ...

```
Group horizontalGroup = groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup()
            .addComponent(aTextArea)
            .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup
                                         (GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)
                    .addComponent(aButton)));

Group verticalGroup = groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
    .addComponent(aTextArea)
    .addComponent(aButton);
```

gives this?

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|+-------------------------------------------------------+     |
||                       aTextArea                       |     |
||                                                       |     |
|+-------------------------------------------------------+     |
|[aButton]                                                     |
|                                                              |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Why does wrapping the aButton in a Parallel Group cause it to ignore the alignment? Adding the alignment also to the aButton itself has no effect.

I want to do something like this in order to have a mixture of groups of leading, trailing and central alignments beneath the aTextArea. It seems to me GroupLayout is rather limited IF it cannot cope with this.

Answer (score 0):

This ...

```
.addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)
    ...
```

specifies that components WITHIN THE GROUP are aligned centrally WITH EACH OTHER.

To align the Group (all elements within the Group) against the parent Group specify the alignment as a parameter of the addGroup() method not of createParallelGroup():

```
.addGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER, groupLayout.createParallelGroup()
    ...
```

I've not found this documented but it seems the *addGroup(GroupLayout.Group group)* form (no alignment specification) applies a LEADING alignment.

In this way SequentialGroups can also be aligned against a parent group.